# Convert a Sharepoint / PowerAutomate date/time into an Excel serial date/time number

Tags: excel, power-automate

I am trying to export an item date/time column from a Sharepoint list into Excel using PowerUtomate. Everything works perfectly, except for the fact that the date is exported as a pattern which Excel does not recognise, i.e. it is not the "45999.00" serial number readable by Excel formulae.

After the "Get items" function, I convert the date from UTC into local time using the "convert time zone" function, which gives me some control over which format it is converted into (eg. "2009-06-15T13:45:30 [s]", or "RFC1123 pattern - Mon, 15 Jun 2009 20:45:30 GMT [r]"), but none of these options yield an Excel-readable number.

There must be some solution, perhaps involving the **ticks(timestamp:string)** function here, when I add the rows to the Excel table, but I cannot figure out what that function would look like:
[an image of the PowerAutomate Flows expression selector with the ticks function selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtkmA.png)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can convert Today's Date into an Excel Number.

```
@{add(div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks('1900-01-01')),864000000000),2)}
```

Create an integer variable and add this code to it.

Comment: The problem is, the string I am trying to convert into an Excel number is not formatted as an ISO standard, or at least that is what the error tells me. The raw output does look like the right ISO standard (eg.  2021-07-31T03:45:00) but I think it is probably a string, and the @{add} function you have described is probably waiting for an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you @Ethan - I was not able to make use of your code, though it looks like it would probably have worked for a more competent person. I really just could not get the input into the @{add} function to wok, as the function kept complaining that the input was not in an ISO-standard format.

So, I created a kludge workaround.

In my table in the Excel document which was the destination for this export, I had created an extra column right after the "date time" column.

This column was left blank in the PowerAutomate Flow.

The formula in the destination table then takes the number generated by the Flow and converts it into an Excel-readable date and time.

The formula I used was:

=DATEVALUE(MID(G2,1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(G2,12,8))

This works for a "sortable" date/time format, like "2021-07-29T10:30:00"

So, it's really not an elegant solution to my problem, but it certainly does the job, and perhaps somebody might find something useful in all this.