# Power Automate - check if valid date

Tags: excel, power-automate, office-scripts

I have a Power Automate flow that calls on an Office Script to read a specific cell in an Excel workbook. That cell is supposed to have a properly formatted date. If it is properly formatted, in order for Power Automate to read that, I set a variable with this expression:

```
addDays('1899-12-30', int(outputs('Run_script_2')?['body/result/DeliveryDate']), 'MM/dd/yy')
```

However, if the output of that script isn't an expected value (i.e. 8.9.2022 instead of 8/9/2022), the flow breaks when trying to run that expression. How can I write an expression that doesn't fail if there isn't the expected Excel-type date? I'd like the expression to equate to null if it's not able to calculate an actual date value.

Comment: Maybe this link will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68587899/convert-a-sharepoint-powerautomate-date-time-into-an-excel-serial-date-time-nu/68590469#68590469

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JavaScript's Date class to convert the date in the cell. When you create an instance of the date object, you provide it with the date value from the cell in its constructor. You can then call the `toLocalDateString()` method of the date object and return that. You can see an example of how to do that below:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let selectedSheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
      let rang: ExcelScript.Range = selectedSheet.getRange("A1") //cell contains the value 8.9.2022
      rang.setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy")
      let date: Date = new Date(rang.getValue() as string);
      return date.toLocaleDateString();
    }
```

Comment: I thought this was working, but if I have, for example, "30047" in the cell, I get this as the output: 12/31/1969.

"30047" isn't a valid date. How can I verify that it's a valid date?

Comment: You can try adding number formatting every time the script runs. I've updated the code to do that. I'm assuming that 30047 is a date in Excel's serial date system. That date would correspond to that value is 4/6/1982. If it is a date from some other system, you may get unexpected results.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. How will that verify that the value is a valid date? If the value is 30047, I don't want that converted to a date. I want that to give some kind of error.

Comment: Ah I see. I misunderstood your previous comment. The issue is that in Excel serial date system 30047 is a valid date. Today's date, 8/12/22, in Excel's serial date system is 44785 for example. Can you try to narrow down the range of values the cell can contain? If not it will be tricky to define rules for what is a valid date and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the NumberFormatCategory, or the specific NumberFormat of the cell to check if it is formatted as a date.

```
if (selectedSheet.getRange("A1").getNumberFormatCategory() == ExcelScript.NumberFormatCategory.date) 
...
```

or

```
if (selectedSheet.getRange("A1").getNumberFormatLocal() == "m/d/yyyy") 
...
```

You can return this boolean to Power Automate as well and build your expression accordingly.

Comment: I tried both of those, and if I have "8.15.22" in the cell, both of those formulas return true.

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. What is the exact code you used? I ran `  console.log(workbook.getActiveCell().getNumberFormatCategory() == ExcelScript.NumberFormatCategory.date);` on a cell containing 8.15.22 and it returned false, but returned true on a cell containing a valid date.

Comment: @JayRathi-Microsoft You can set date formats on cell values that don't contain date values. e.g. I can set a cell containing the value "Hello world!" to the format of date. If the user previously enters a date in a cell, Excel will format as a date. But if the user later enters a value that is not a date, Excel will not necessarily change the date format to a different format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue, because my users use the excel date field for more than a date, such as entering "NA", "Not Known", "TBD", etc.

Use the INT() function on the date value. Configure the next step using the "Configure run after" setting to be "Failed" only. Configure the step after that to be "is skipped".

In my case, in the failed case, I simply copy the excel value into a string I'll use for my output file. If the INT() succeeds, I run a condition statement because I want to blank out future dates but leave past dates